# Files Listed in Emacs Find-Files

Tags: emacs

I was using Emacs on another terminal today and I noticed that when I hit C-x C-f to open a file that Emacs showed "Loading Tramp..." and then listed the files.  I could either type my desired directory/file or I could use the left/right arrow key and Return to shift through directories and open a file.  I was totally awesome.  I am familiar with Tramp mode and started fiddling with it but I could not figure out how to get it to work, or if the two are even related, on my machine.

How do I get a file tree that I can use arrow keys with in Emacs?

This is how it appears on the other terminal:

```
Find file: .../dir1/dir1/{css/ | try.org | misc.txt | .emacs}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That likely was `ido-mode`, which is bundled with Emacs. Put this in the init file:

```
(ido-mode)
```

While it's on, it will rebind some common commands to its own versions that use this visual interface.

Tramp mode is not related. It just gets loaded if `ido-use-virtual-buffers` is `t` and you visited some remote files recently.