# How to list files in emacs

Tags: file, emacs, dired

I would like to list files in a directory as in the following picture
[image]
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49472114/6747994 author: [@ocodo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311660/ocodo) license: [CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

Comment: you're screen is showing `M-x dired`, which is normally how you would list a directory, see also `dired-jump`, since you're using `projectile`, you also have `projectile-dired`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hit `C-x` `C-f` Source: [Files Listed in Emacs Find-Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13871666/6747994)

this means

- Open Emacs (Terminal)

  - Press Super-Key (also known as Windows-Key) and release
  - type `emacs`
  - click on `GNU Emacs 25 (Ter...` or similar
- Press `ctrl` & `x` on the keyboard at the same time, then release both keys
- Press `ctrl` & `f` on the keyboard at the same time, then release both keys
- type in the folder-path, where you want to navigate

Answer (score 2):

- **`C-x d`** opens Dired on the directory you mention letting you perform actions on files that you mark in the list.
- **`C-x C-d`** lists the directory. Similar to Dired, but without the possibility to act on listed files.

See the Emacs manual, node [Dired Enter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Enter.html).